# using unique_ptr with custom deleter for GError

Tags: c++, gstreamer, unique-ptr

using unique_ptr with custom deleter for c functions that return a ptr is pretty straight forward, but how would i use it for functions that take ptr of ptr as parameter (like GError)

I have faced this in couple of cases but but did not find a straightforward way to do this. am i missing something?

```cpp
using Element = std::unique_ptr<GstElement, void (*)(GstElement*)>;
using Error = std::unique_ptr<GError, void (*)(GError*)>;
...
GError* plain_err;
Element pipeline(gst_parse_launch(str, &plain_err), object_unref); // ok

Error uniq_err {nullptr, error_free};
Element pipeline(gst_parse_launch(str, &(uniq_err.get())), object_unref); // error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

The only way I could think of is by assigning it later

```cpp
GError* plain_err;
Element pipeline(gst_parse_launch(str, &plain_err), object_unref);
Error uniq_err {plain_err, error_free};
plain_error = nullptr;
```

Comment: Don't tag C++ questions with the C tag unless you are particularly fond of downvotes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The question is about using plain pointers from c inside c++ unique_ptr, do i still just tag c++?

Comment: @tejas  Unless you want your program to be compiled with a C compiler there is no need to tag with [C].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found returning a tuple from a lambda to be marginally better,

```
auto [pipeline, err] = [&]() noexcept {
    GError* err = nullptr;
    auto* pipeline = gst_parse_launch(str, &err);
    return std::tuple{Element{pipeline, object_unref}, Error{err, error_free}};
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code:

```
GError* plain_err;
Element pipeline(gst_parse_launch(str, &plain_err), object_unref);
```

suggest that `gst_parse_launch()` allocates `GError*` and returns it. In this case, you cannot use `unique_ptr` your way. Because `unique_ptr` just manages lifetime of a pointer.

You can try something like this for managing your pointer using `unique_ptr`:

```
struct ErrorRelease {
    void operator()(GError* ptr) {
        // release pointer
    }
};
using Error = std::unique_ptr<GError, ErrorRelease>;

GError* plain_err;
Element pipeline(gst_parse_launch(str, &plain_err), object_unref);

Error uniq_err(plain_err);
```

After this, you just must remember not to free `plain_err` manually because it is managed by your `unique_ptr`. It is OK to assign another value to it, just don't release it manually.

Comment: this is more or less the way I have mentioned in the question, or have I missed something?

Comment: @tejas yea, it is. I just didn't see in your post, so I added it to my answer.